# How can i Prevent Kinematic object not to pass through another rigidbody object

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, collider

[image: ri]I am developing an oculus Home like project where i am facing a problem of object passes through walls and other objects. The scene is described as, Ialt texthave an object that has Box Collider and an Rigidbody (Gravity false , Kinematic true) A wall and a Floor with Box Collider and Rigidbody(Gravity false , Kinematic False) I am moving an object with hands movement. Translate object near and far using thumbstick, the problem is that when i move object far the object pass through the wall and floor. As you can see in the image below the object is passing through in the walls and the floor. Please help me and suggest a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the idea behing Kinematic objects is that interaction with Physics will not alter their transforms, so they will pass through other static or kinematic objects. To alter that you can either not use Kinematic rb's or detect collisions manually and adjust for collision results

Comment: i use kinematic because i need to pick the object with my virtual hand.

Comment: i have unchecked IsKinematic check but still no change :/

Comment: try using rigidbody.position and rigidbody.rotation instead of transform, it should respect collisions then

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one of your collider's `Is Trigger` set to true.

If the collider on your object has the `Is Trigger` property set to true then the collider will pass through other colliders but if it's not a trigger then it'll always collide with other non-trigger colliders. So as long as you have two non-trigger colliders they'll always collide no matter the rigid-body and if you need the `Is Trigger` property set to true there's a workaround you can use two types of colliders on a single object one a trigger and another a non-trigger preferably a Mesh Collider (so the trigger collider will have space to be triggered).